# Black screen half way through Windows 7 Repair Install, laptop recoverable?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, repair-install

Half way through the Windows 7 Repair install the monitor drivers seem to have corrupted. The screen works fine up to the Windows logo on a black background, then the screen goes dead.

Everything is still working underneath, key presses seem to affect the hard disk, caps lock works, I can even hibernate with the sleep key, but I can't get Windows running so I can install the monitor drivers (or do anything else).

Repair Install did ask me to uninstall the ATI Catalyst drivers, but the screen worked fine after.

I have tried:

- Restarting
- Typing my Win 7 license key and pressing return
- Connecting to an external monitor via HDMI
- Booting from a USB or DVD Windows 7 installer disk and trying the Startup Repair, Restore,
  installing drivers (I think they only go into memory), etc.
- Booting from Win7 install DVD or USB and using the DOS prompt, copying fresh copies of the monitor driver files inf/monitor.pnf inf/monitor.inf and sys32/drivers/monitor.sys then rebooting
- Trying every option in the BIOS (although nothing was promising - was hoping to turn off PnP but there was no option)
- Trying a new repair install by booting from the Windows 7 disk - it boots, loads fine, but at the compatibility check demands I start Windows then run the installer from within Windows

Any ideas on anything at all I can try? I'm pretty desperate to recover the partition as there are months invested in some of the software on there, especially VBox servers that aren't porting, Traktor media catalogues, etc.

Huge thanks
Chris

EDIT: I have an Acronis disk image backup of the machine a few months old. It is equally corrupted as my Windows install, so no solution, but I could pull off any driver files etc, if I knew hwo to plug them into my 'repaired' install.

Comment: tried safe mode?

Comment: Long shot - try attaching an external monitor.

Comment: Thanks. External monitor didn't work (on HDMI), and I don't get a boot menu when I boot into the repair install. I get a boot menu with safe mode, monitor modes, etc, only when I boot off the Win7 install disk, for which the monitor works anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to recover it if windows restore isn't working would be to use a boot-able live CD like [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php). Boot from it and copy all of you files to a flash drive or a external hard-drive and then reinstall windows.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to restore the Windows install, I have access to the file system via the repair DOS prompt and may use a SATA caddy if the laptop is dead. I just can't believe that I have to give up on the Windows install just due to a monitor driver error - seems ridiculous.

Comment: That's windows for you.

Comment: Unfortunately "that's windows for you" comes as close as I get to an answer. If it was a fresh install, in case anyone's looking, you can apparently [access the Device Manager](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15856-device-manager-access-during-windows-7-installation.html) for the nascent install by running a DOS prompt then typing compmgmtlauncher from Windows/System32.